# Passing a list as Parameter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner to functional programming and Haskell as a programming language. After given an input of numbers from the command line I want to put those numbers into a list, then pass that list as a parameter to calculate its sum. Here's what I am working on:

```
import Data.List

iotxt :: IO ()

main :: IO ()

l1 = []


iotxt = do a <- getLine

        -- read in numbers that are not equal to -1
           insert (read a) l1

           if (not ((read a) == -1.0)) 
               then iotxt
           else do return ()
main = do

        putStrLn("Enter a number [-1 to quit]")
        iotxt

        -- size of the list 
        print(length [l1])
        -- sum
```

But when I attempt to place the values inside the list I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `[a1]'
    In the return type of a call of `insert'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: insert (read a) l1
    In the expression:
      do { a <- getLine;
           insert (read a) l1;
           if (not ((read a) == - 1.0)) then iotxt else do { return () } }
```

Comment: Note how Javran's solution and mine use two different techniques for "updating" the list: I pass it on as a parameter, explicitly updated with each input step. This represents the destructive updating you proposed in your original trial. The alternative, perhaps nicer conceptually, is to forget also about this explicit updating-and-passing and instead just combine the results after each recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with you're code.

Starting from the bottom up, first, `length [l1]` doesn't make sense. Any `[` `]` with only one item in between is just that: a list with a single item, so the `length` will always be `1`. You certainly mean `length l1` here, i.e. *length of the list `l1`*, not *length of the list ᴄᴏɴᴛᴀɪɴɪɴɢ only `l1`*.

Next, you have this `iotxt` and try to make it modify the "global variable" `l1`. You can't do that, Haskell does not have any such thing as mutable global variables – for good reasons; global mutable state is considered evil even in imperative languages. Haskell *kind of* has local variables, through `IORef`s, but using those without good reason is frowned upon. You don't really need them for something like this here.

The correct thing to do is to scrap this global `l1` binding, forget about mutating variables. Which brings us to the question of how to pass on the information acquired in `iotxt`. Well, the obvious *functional* thing to do is, *returning it*. We need to make that explicit in the type (which is again *a good thing*, so we actually know how to use the function):

```
ioTxt :: IO [Int]
```

Such a function can then nicely be used in `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter a number [-1 to quit]"
    l1 <- ioTxt
    print $ length l1
```

You see: almost the same as your approach, but with proper explicit introduction of `l1` *where you need it*, rather than somewhere completely different.

What's left to do is implementing `ioTxt`. This now also needs a local `l1` variable since we have scrapped the global one. And when you implement a loop as such a recursive call, you need to pass an *updated* version of it to each instantiation. The recursion itself should be done on a locally-defined function.

```
ioTxt :: IO [Int]
ioTxT = go []  -- Start with empty list. `go` is a widespread name for such simple "loop functions".
 where go l1 = do
         a <- getLine
         let x = read a :: Int
         case x of
          (-1) -> return l1
          _    -> go (insert x l1)
```

In the last line, note that `insert` does not modify the list `l1`, it rather creates a new one that equals the old one except for having the new element in it. And then passes that to the next loop-call, so effectively you get an updated list for each recursive call.

Also note that you probably shouldn't use `insert` here: that's specifically for placing the new element at the right position in an *ordered list*. If you just want to accumulate the values in some way, you can simply use

```
          _    -> go $ x : l1
```

Answer (score 2):

In haskell, there are no variables, everything is immutable. So you shouldn't define `l1` and change its value later, which doesn't work.

Instead you should think how to write `iotxt` properly and let it collect elements and pass the input list back to your `main`.

In your `iotxt`, you can think about these two situations:

- if the input is `-1`, then we can just pass an empty list `[]` back, wrap it inside the `IO` by `return []`
- if the input is not `-1`, we can first store this value somewhere, say `result`. After that, we should call `iotxt` recursively and let this inner `iotxt` handle the rest of the inputs. Finally, we will get return value `rest`, then we just simply put `result` and `rest` together.

Moreover, you can think of `IO a` like some program (which might have side effects like reading from input or writing to output) that returns a value of type `a`. According to the definition of your `iotxt`, which is a program that reads input until meeting a `-1` and gives you the list in return, the type signature for `iotxt` should be `IO [Float]`.

There's a `length [l1]` in your code, which constructs a list with only one element(i.e. `l1`) and thus `length [l1]` will always return `1`. Instead of doing this, you can say `length l1`, which calculates the length of `l1`.

Finally, you don't need to group function arguments by parenthese, just simply say `f x` if you want to call `f` with `x`.

I've modified your code a little bit, hope it can give you some help.

```
import Data.List

-- iotxt reads from stdin, yields [Float]
-- stop reading when "-1" is read
iotxt :: IO [Float]

main :: IO ()

iotxt = do
    a <- getLine
    -- read in numbers that are not equal to -1
    let result = (read a) :: Float
    if (not (result == -1.0)) 
        then do
            -- read rest of the list from stdin
            rest <- iotxt
            -- put head & tail together
            return $ result:rest
        else do return []

main = do
    putStrLn("Enter a number [-1 to quit]")
    l1 <- iotxt
    -- size of the list 
    print $ length l1
    -- sum 
    print $ sum l1
```